# How to play audio file of URL link using AVAudioPlayer in iphone objective-c

Tags: objective-c, iphone, avaudioplayer

I am creating a voice communication feature in my application that sends voice notes between users via a web server, however during
 testing I am experiencing an error with playing back message I created
 with **AVAudioPlayer**. The **AVAudioplayer** just returns a ***null*** value.

How do I play an audio file from the ***URL link with AVAudioPlayer***?

```
if (!self.audioRecorder.recording) {

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[@"http://.../sound.mp4"]];
        NSLog(@"%@", url);
        NSLog(@"PlayBack");

        NSData *audioData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
        NSString *filePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
                                                                   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"sound1.caf"];
        [audioData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];


        NSError *error;
        NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
        self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileURL error:&error];
        if (self.audioPlayer == nil) {
            NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
            NSLog(@"%@", [self.audioPlayer description]);
        }else
            [self.audioPlayer play];
    }else [self.audioRecorder stop];
```

Comment: check error object what does it say?

Comment: What returns a NULL value? `sound1.caf` vs `sound.mp4` is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

please try out this code:

```
- (void) playMessageSound : (NSString *) filename{

self.soundFilename = filename;
//[[RBDMuteSwitch sharedInstance] detectMuteSwitch];
NSString *name = [filename stringByDeletingPathExtension];
NSString *extension = [filename pathExtension];
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:name ofType:extension];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSError *error;
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:fileUrl error:&error];
self.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
self.audioPlayer.volume = 1.0;
[self.audioPlayer play];
```

}

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
 NSString* resourcePath = @""; //your url
        NSData *_objectData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:resourcePath]];
        NSError *error;

        app.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:_objectData error:&error];
        app.audioPlayer.numberOfLoops = 0;
        app.audioPlayer.volume = 4.0f;
        [app.audioPlayer prepareToPlay];

        if (app.audioPlayer == nil)
        NSLog(@"%@", [error description]);
        else
        [app.audioPlayer play];
```